# Unable to set Bootstrap $primary theme color in create-react-app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, create-react-app, bootstrap-5, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to set custom Bootstrap's `$primary` and `secondary` values in `$theme-colors`. I can create new custom colors and add them to the theme color map and consume them but I cannot override Bootstrap's defaults.

I'm using [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) version 2.7.2 and [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/) with react-scripts version 5.0.1 and [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) 5.2.3. I've read the `create-react-app` relevant documentation [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-bootstrap/#using-a-custom-theme) and the react-bootstrap docs [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#customize-bootstrap). They both suggest seemly the same steps, so thats basically what I'm doing now.

Installed `sass`

```
npm install sass
```

create `scss/custom.scss` and tried tests such as:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/variables';

$primary: $orange;

$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, (
  "primary": $primary,
  "myblue": #0928af
));

@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

import `custom.scss` in `index.jsx`

```
import './scss/custom.scss'
```

In the case above I can access `myblue` which leads me to believe sass is working in my project but primary is unchanged and remains the default blue. Most issues I've read are from importing bootstrap scss source in the wrong order which I think is correct here.

Seems like I'm importing Bootstrap variable again after this scss import and setting `$theme-colors` back to their default values but I'm not sure where this would be and have looked/searched.

Any thoughts or tips on troubleshooting this would be great!

Comment: Your code should work. I'd recommend trying Bootstrap 5.3.x .. there were several theme/color bugs in v5.2.3

Comment: Thanks Carol. I actually downgraded from 5.3.0 while trying to troubleshoot. Regardless I have reverted, and reinstalled 5.3.0 and the problem still persists with:

```  "bootstrap": "^5.3.0-alpha3",
```

**package.json**

Comment: So I just figured it out, I was using a 3rd party component library that imports "bootstrap-css-only" and that was messing up bootstrap definitions. Thanks!